# iOS Local Notofications not firing while app is in background

Tags: ios, background, multitasking, uilocalnotification, localnotification

When my iOS app exits, it registers a series of local notifications, which update the badge number at specific times. The local notifications do not bring up a popup, they simply update the badge. On my old iPod touch which does not support multitasking, this works perfectly. However, on my multitasking enabled devices, I am experiencing a very strange bug: when I have "exited" the app (i.e. it is still running in the background, but I am doing something else), the local notifications are not firing. Is there any reason why the local notifications would not fire when the app is in the background?

The code to create the local notifications runs in a loop (I create a bunch of them):

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = totalCount; // a number generated earlier in the code
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.fireDate = endDate; // a date generated earlier
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [localNotification release];
```

And also I have created the following function in my app delegate, which tells me how many notifications are set up before the app enters the background:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"# Notifications: %d", [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]);
}
```

The app constantly tells me that there are 64 notifications (the number that should be set up) when it enters the background.

Comment: Can you show us the code for firing the local notification?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following from Apple's developers docs:
"Each application on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications. The system discards scheduled notifications in excess of this limit, keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the soonest. Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification."

Could you problem be related to the number of notifications been scheduled?

You can find further information in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html

Answer (score 0):

Well @Jason you need to set the `alertBody` of the `local notification` atleast to show an alert view, thats all there is to it.

Also if you dont wont to show the view option in the alert box then set the `hasAction` attribute to NO.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer my question exactly... I am not interested in showing the alert view. I just want to update the badge number.

Comment: also you need to check the fire date, if the date is before the current date than the notification wont be fired just the application did receive local notification method in your app delegate will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
       let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "App has been entered in background" 
        notification.alertAction = "open" 
        notification.fireDate = NSDate() 
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName 
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
```